# eqref in reftex

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

I'm using Emacs + AUCTeX + refTeX. I've added `(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)` to my `init.el`file and everything seems to work fine except for one thing. When I choose to reference a label using `C-c )` it doesn't offer me `\eqref`as reference style which I understand it should given that I'm using AUCTeX and having enabled the plugging-in functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Just reference an equation, we're will be automatically used.

Comment: It seems to be doing that now, wasn't before (strange). By the way it seems that it recognizes the word equation (and the German equivalent!) and automatically only offers me equation labels. Neat.

Comment: (sorry, in my previous comment, autocompletion replaced "eqref" with "we're")

Comment: This question seems to be solved as per the comment.